# Choosing a different python version to run code

Tags: python, windows

a) I have a code that works fine if I choose Python 2.5 but it gives me errors when using python 2.7. I have easily fixed the problem in windows by choosing python 2.5 as the default program. But, it seems that cmd does not follow this change. How could I fix this?

b) what is the difference between running a script using python.exe vs. pythonw.exe? I read somewhere that upon using pythonw.exe, I will not see the cmd window that pops out and disappears. But for my case, this is not true and I actually see the cmd window. Also, if I use python.exe I get an error from running my script but not when I use pythonw.exe.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Just like a doctor cannot diagnose you if you just say "I don't feel well", we can't help if you just say "I get errors"

Comment: I am using the zipfile module in my script and somewhere in my script I try to save a file using the 'wb' option which saves data in binary form. However, upon running python 2.7, I get the runtimeError: Zipfile() requires mode "r", "w", or "a". Now I have run the same same script in python 2.5. The python.exe seems to give the same error (I can't see the error cause I am just clicking on the file and before seeing the error, the cmd window disappears) but pythonw.exe works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: You mention python(w).exe and cmd, so you're most likely on windows.

1. You probably selected "use python 2.n" somewhere in your IDE (whichever one you may use). That works fine as long as you ONLY execute your scripts from there. From any arbitrary other place on your system, windows (or any other OS) makes use of environment variables PATH, in this case. (right-click My Computer > advanced > environment variables or something). It probably contains the path to python27.exe C:/Python27, change that to C:/Python25. If multiple directories are used, first order takes precedence.
2. pythonw.exe is a custom executable related to early pywin32 development by Mark Hammond I believe, and yes it should supress the console window during startup.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your useful tips. Using virtualenv is not an option for me since I have to install the program on a company pc and that might cause problems. Yuka's remark about changing the order of paths in system environment on windows was the tip that I was looking for. This has resolved the issue. Although I still am not sure why pythonw runs my script successfully and python.exe does not. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Ah, yes, I failed to notice, thanks David. However, if anything else it was mentioned to establish my answer was targeting the right platform, and differentiate from the other answers who where obvious targeted at unix based systems (apt-get, bashrc, etc). Not to indicate in any way that Ramen did not provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper program, with virtualenv you can choose the python environment of your choice.

Exemple if you would like execute "App A" with python 2.7, you can do it with virtualenv (example for Debian)

**Install a packages**

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-pip git 
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

**Configure virtualenvwrapper**

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bashrc
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
EOF
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Prepare App A environment**

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python2.7 app_a
add2virtualenv /opt/app_a
```

**run you app**

```
workon app_a
yourscrypt.py
```

or

```
$HOME/.virtualenvs/app_a/bin/python yourscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way for to switch easily between different Python versions is to use virtualenv. However, in your case you have changed the file association for the .py extension. But you have not modified the `PATH` environment variable. So when you double click on a .py file, you get the Python version that you want. But when you execute `python script.py` at the command line, the `PATH` variable is used to find `PATH`, and the system finds the wrong one. You could resolve that by modifying your `PATH` variable. But, virtualenv would be better!

The difference between pythonw.exe and python.exe? The former targets the WINDOWS subsystem, and the latter targets the CONSOLE subsystem. You typically use the former for GUI programs, and the latter for console programs. More information on subsystems can be found on MSDN: [/SUBSYSTEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx).

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) also covers the topic from a Python perspective:

> Python scripts (files with the extension .py) will be executed by python.exe by default. This executable opens a terminal, which stays open even if the program uses a GUI. If you do not want this to happen, use the extension .pyw which will cause the script to be executed by pythonw.exe by default (both executables are located in the top-level of your Python installation directory). This suppresses the terminal window on startup.

If you see a console window when you run pythonw then you are either starting from an existing console window, or your program is creating one. Why does your program fail when run through python but not pythonw? I don't know. You did not show your program, or your error, and my crystal ball is currently being serviced!  ;-)

---

Having said all of that, and attempted to answer the questions that you asked, I don't think you are tackling your problem the right way. It would seem to me that the right solution would be to fix your code so that it works in Python 2.7.